# MySQL Error 1604 near ') NOT NULL, )' at line 1

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> USE bitcoin;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL, ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, ) ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 1
mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL, );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, )' at line 1
mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL, );
```

This error is being thrown when using MYSQL Command Line on Debian. I am trying to create a table with the given values.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL)' at line 1
mysql>
```

Doesnt work either.

Comment: you have an extra comma at the end of your statement `btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL,`

Comment: Remove the last comma (that precedes the closing parenthesis).

Comment: You should also remove `(30)` from your `btc` field so it will be `btc DOUBLE NOT NULL`

Comment: mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL)' at line 1
mysql>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `,` between the last `NOT NULL` and the closing parenthesis in each `CREATE TABLE` statement, and a width specifier on the `DOUBLE(30)` that I don't believe is valid:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  btc    DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL, ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
               ^^^^             ^
```

Remove it, so the end of the statement is `btc DOUBLE NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this mysql> CREATE TABLE btc ( uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL)' at line 1
mysql>
 But no luck

Comment: So did you check the documentation to find out whether `DOUBLE(30)` is a valid column type in your MySQL version?

Comment: The problem was with double, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
btc DOUBLE(30) NOT NULL, ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
                       ^
```

get rid of this comma